# What's the difference between "drawViewHierarchyInRect" and "drawInContext"?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

There are two options in having snapshot of a UIView:

option1:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sampleView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
sampleView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(sampleView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

option2:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sampleView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
sampleView.layer.drawInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

At present, i found that option1 must use the main queue, which is a serial queue. However, option2 can do its job in the background on concurrent queue